# Capturing regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex, capturing-group

I would like to use the regular expressions in Python to get everything that is after a `</html>` tag, an put it in a string. So I tried to understand how to do it in Python but I was not able to make it work. Can anyone explain me how to do this ridiculous simple task ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
m = re.match(".*<\html>(.*)",my_html_text_string)
print m.groups()
```

or even better

```
print my_html_string.split("</html>")[-1]
```

Comment: Both are good but thanks for showing me how group capture works in Python !

Comment: By the way it is a / and not a \

Answer (score 6):

You can do this without a regular expression:

```
text[text.find('</html>')+7:]
```

Comment: even better than my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

text = 'foo</html>bar'
m = re.search('</html>(.*)', text)
print m.group(1)
```

Comment: 1) It didn't work - you had `<\html>` in there, which is obviously wrong. 2) Code without a single word of explanation. 3) Using the wrong tool for the job (regular expressions), even though the OP requested it because he doesn't know better.

Comment: I would imagine it was downvoted because the OP asked for an explanation rather than a code snippet. He states that he's tried what he thought would work, but doesn't know why it didn't.

Comment: @lukas 1) fixed almost immediately :)  2) concise code is often better alone than with a [possibly conflicting] explanation. 3) question specifically asked for an answer using regex.  I'm not a mind reader, so just assume he has a valid reason for not using an html parser.

Comment: 1) It still means you pasted untested code :-) But my downvote is gone, it does work now even though I don't think it's a good idea. With 2) I simply don't agree. Concise code is good of course, but it's always better with an explanation why and how it works. Not sure what you mean by "possibly conflicting". 3) Yes, the question asked for RE. But it's the wrong tool for the job, and showing him a solution that's easier and performs tens of times better, as Radu did, is much more helpful in my opinion. And since he's interested in the stuff after `</html>`, he's not parsing HTML at all.

Comment: Parsing HTML using regular expressions is impossible anyway. Not just a bad idea, it simply can't be done.